# downloading multiple images into a list with j2me

Tags: java, java-me

I am trying to create a list of images and text. The problem is that the images are being downloaded from the web.

How do I use threads in j2me to download images from the web without freezing the application?

Answer (score 2):

Study tutorial, like this one: [Networking, User Experience, and Threads](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading/)

> This article explains how your MIDlet can make network connections without compromising your user interface. It includes six iterative examples that illustrate multithreaded networking and the use of a wait screen...