# downloading images at the background with j2me and lwuit

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have a lists of images to be downloaded from the internet and populated in a list together with description text beside each image.

The problem I am having now is that the app gets freeze when the images are being downloaded that I understand.`

I created a thread to do the downloading, the class is below. I use the `start` method to start thread but the image will be null not until I used `run`.

```
public class GetImage extends Thread {

public String imgString;
private String url;
private Label label;
public Image img = null;

public GetImage(String url, Label label){
    this.url = url;
    this.label = new Label();
    this.label = label;
}

public Image getPic()
{

    return img;
}
public void run()
{
   this.getImage_(); 
   this.label.setIcon(img.scaledHeight(60));

}

public void getImage_()
{
    HttpConnection hc = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    StringBuffer messageBuffer  = new StringBuffer();

     try{
        hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(this.url,Connector.READ);
        dis = new DataInputStream(hc.openDataInputStream());
        int ch;
        long len = hc.getLength();
        if(len != -1)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < len; i++)
                if((ch = dis.read())!=-1)
                    messageBuffer.append((char)ch);
        }
        else
        {
            while((ch = dis.read()) != -1)
                messageBuffer.append((char)ch);
        }

        this.img = Image.createImage(messageBuffer.toString().getBytes(),0,messageBuffer.toString().length());
        dis.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ae){
        messageBuffer.append("Error");
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if (hc != null) hc.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored) {}
        try {
            if (dis != null) dis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored) {}
        try {
            if (dos != null) dos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }

   //return this.img;
}

}
```

and the listrenderer to display the list:

```
public class ListRenderer extends Label implements ListCellRenderer {

public ListRenderer()
{
    super();
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object o, int i, boolean bln) {
     //cast the value object into a Content

    Contents entry = (Contents)o;
    //get the icon of the Content and set it for this label
    this.setIcon(entry.getIcon());
    //get the text of the Content and set it for this label
    this.setText(entry.getText());
    //set transparency
    getStyle().setBgTransparency((byte)128);
    //set background and foreground colors
    //depending on whether the item is selected or not
    if(bln)
    {
        getStyle().setBgColor(0xffcc33);
        getStyle().setFgColor(0x000000);
    }
    else
    {
       getStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);

    }
    return this;
}

public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
    setText("");
    setIcon(null);
    getStyle().setBgColor(0xffcc33);
    getStyle().setBgTransparency(80);
    return this;
}

}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you might be creating your thread and calling `run` instead of `start`. The `start` method will make the asynchronous magic happen.

Comment: yea, i use the start but the image will be null not until i used run.

Comment: the errors you're getting are because you don't properly synchronize. Re-check the [tutorial suggested in answer to your prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9959124/839601) - all these cryptic `synchronized`, `wait`, `notify` are there for a reason

Answer (score 0):

The comments you got are probably correct. This [blog post](http://gadgets.coolman.ca/genericlistcellrenderer-revisiting-the-twitter-client-demo/) shows something that seems similar to what you are trying to achieve. Its in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) but most of the code should be applicable to LWUIT just as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, your comments were very useful. I finally used the callSeriallyAndWait() method exposed by the lwuit EDT and it's really worked.